# Cloudfront + ELB with SSL and Apache vhost setup

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have configured webserver front ending with AWS ELB and cloudfront. I have deployed SSL certificate on load balancer (ELB) for https connection.
2 listener protocol we have set 
 1) soruce -> 80 -> ELB -> 80 ->  EC2 webserver
 2) soruce -> 443 -> ELB -> 80 ->  EC2 webserver

Following of my blog post describe entire setup in detail
http://www.cloudometry.in/2015/04/dns-entry-confusion-for-aws-elb-backed.html

The issue is We are able to open dummy test index.html file but when i try to open our application index.php then everything falls apart and browser keeps on refreshing.

i have noticed following log in webserver's access log
[26/Apr/2015:17:08:21 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 125 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6 (internal dummy connection)"

does anyone has faced this issue?
Am i missing any configuration?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: The traffic from the ELB will always be HTTP as it handles the HTTPS traffic to the user but to the server it's HTTP, is that the reason it is resulting in loop?.   I have found related post here http://serverfault.com/questions/677560/redirect-loop-when-forcing-https

Comment: i am not using .htaccess so where do i have to make RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] changes

Comment: i am getting following trace when we open site in browser:    http://pastebin.com/xrNcugDX